# Passing an empty string as a commandline argument using a bash variable to a command

Tags: bash

I have a daemon that can be run manually from a bash shell like this:

```
daemon-binary --name some-name --separator '' /path/to/file
```

The command-line options for this daemon should be configured in `/etc/default/daemonname` like this:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="--name some-name --separator '' /path/to/file"
```

This config is sourced by an init-script that starts the daemon passing the commandline options found in `DAEMON_OPTS` like this:

```
daemon-binary "$DAEMON_OPTS"
```

The result is, that the string `''` gets quoted again and instead of an empty string the `daemon-binary` gets passed two single. So in fact the result is the same as calling:

```
daemon-binary --name some-name --separator "''" /path/to/file
```

As far as I understand bash splits the `DAEMON_OPTS` at each whitespace, then quotes all the pieces and passes them to the `daemon-binary`.

Is there any way to write the bash variable `DAEMON_OPTS` such that what's currently being expanded to `"''"` will be expanded into an empty string?

Answer (score 3):

This is a case where you *don't* want to quote the expansion of `DAEMON_OPTS`:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="--name some-name --separator '' /path/to/file"
daemon-binary $DAEMON_OPTS
```

Comment: if this is bash, you can also use `DAEMON_OPTS=("--name" "some-name" "--separator" "" "/path/to/file")` and `daemon-binary "${DAEMON_OPTS[@]}"`